# How to determine maximum software volume output

Tags: audio, sound-card

We have a rather unique setup for some experiments that involves a copper coil hooked up to a couple of amplifiers, which are hooked up to an external sound card, which are hooked up to a laptop (via USB).  The laptop/sound card/amp volume is set to max and then we have a piece of software that generates a sound with a volume set within the application.  This will generate a current on the copper coil which we can measure using a clamp meter.

The problem we are running into is that we sometimes need a new laptop (the old one dies, or we want to set up another rig) and the model we bought last time is unavailable, the new one we buy might not work and we can't tell in advance which laptops will work and which ones will not.

The ones that do not work don't get "loud" enough.  When the sound plays at 100% and all the volumes are set to max, it might read 500 amps, but with a different laptop it might bet 800 amps or higher.

Theoretically since we are using an external sound card, the actual speakers are bypassed and it shouldn't really matter what the hardware on the laptop itself is, I would think.  I have searched on the laptop to see if there is any kind of volume limiting application and I can't find one.

Does anyone have any idea of what even we should be looking for that would determine it's ability to put out the correct signal? (preferably consistently and without wearing out in a year, but even just having an idea of what should work at all would be good).

Edit just to clarify/simplify:  When we send a maximum volume sound on laptop A to the USB sound card, it clocks in at 800+ amps.  When we send a maximum volume sound on laptop B to the USB sound card, it clocks in at 500 amps.  How can we tell before we buy we're going to end up with an A laptop and not a B laptop?  What piece of hardware is different?

Comment: You just need any piece of pro audio software, where 0dBFS send a recognised digital maximum to your external DAC. The DAC is then responsible for producing the correct signal voltage from that. It sounds like you're trying to do scientific measurement on a 'see if it's loud enough' analogue output, dependant on the op amp of any given device… that's really not how to start. If that's not the case, then you need to clarify your current setup.

Comment: Our goal is to produce amperage on the line so that other instruments can read it and recognize it and we can train the other instruments.  For example we want to run 800 amps for five seconds, wait for five seconds at 0 amps, 600 amps for five seconds, etc.  The software application we wrote allows us to calibrate it (plays 6 different levels of sound then we feed back how many amps each level was, so it generates a curve of software-generated output -> real output), then we can program it to output a sequence of amps with various timings.  The maximum volume isn't the end-goal.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to measure your output without knowing the input. You need your entire signal chain to be calibrated, otherwise you're just whistling in the wind. You'd probably be better off asking this in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ where they might know better questions to ask you for clarification. I'm a sound engineer, I push faders, I don't measure voltages. "Maximum volume" is not a scientific measurement. You need to calibrate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try there.  The entire chain down to the cables is the same between laptops, and the software used is the same, the only difference is the laptops themselves (and I guess whatever bloatware/settings came with them).

Comment: Digital output is a known quantity. 0dBFS is the same no matter where you output it. You then need to know what your 'FS' is, which is the job of your DAC. You need to know what units you're working in too - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel there's more than 'one deciBel'.

Comment: What I keep calling the "external sound card" is a Behringer UMC202HD USB audio interface.  That is the same physical object used for both laptops.  Is that the DAC?  Since a USB line is running to that device the signal cannot have been converted to analog prior to that, right?

Comment: Have you checked Windows sound settings for loudness or some other "boost" setting on the output?

Comment: I believe that your amplifiers located outside behind the sound card should have a gain reserve so that the functionality of the whole assembly does not depend so much on the output level of the sound card. You should be able to compensate for any lower level of output from the card by changing the gain of the external amplifier. I suggest inserting a small adjustable preamp between the sound card and the external amplifier (e.g. for high-quality headphones which need a higher level of voltage). Then you will not be limited by the choice of computer.

Comment: The setup is laptop -> Behringer UMC202HD USB audio interface -> 2x Rockville amps.  Everything on them is set as high as possible (and we had to change from one amp to two to get to the amperage we want at consistent levels)

Answer (score 0):

I believe we resolved the issue.  Settings -> sound settings -> advanced to get a Win95-style settings interface for each of the sound devices.  Right click on the device and hit properties.  Find sound enhancements.  On some devices it is an on an "enhancement" tab, on others the "advanced" tab.  Even if none of the enhancements are checked off, if there is a box that says "disable all" make sure it is checked.

If there is a setting in one of those tabs that makes the sounds quieter when communication is detected, disable that as well.

Now the device that couldn't get over 550 amps hit over 1k without even going full strength.

Leaving the amps off over the weekend because maybe we overdid it on the test, but will do a full calibration and test on Tuesday to confirm it worked properly.

(Also, FYI, the cross-post to electronics.stackexchange.com that was recommended was closed as off-topic)

Comment: This still sounds completely Rube Goldberg/Heath Robinson. What is it you're actually doing that needs such a massive trigger output? You can run an entire sound mix & light show from a laptop these days; the only actual *serious* power being needed for the final output to speakers & lights themselves. All triggering is done at microprocessor level, in software.

Comment: We're putting amps out over a simulated power line to calibrate other devices that detect amperage on real power lines.  The amps are the goal.

Comment: Hmm… fair enough :)